# Can anyone recommend a decent free stop watch widget for MacOSX?

Tags: dashboard-widget

I would like something that is simple to use.

Answer (score 8):

Depending on the functionalities you want :

- Simple & Design : [iChrono](http://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/status/ichrono.html)

  [image: ichrono]
- More features & like a real stopwatch : [Stopwatch widget](http://creativebits.org/stopwatch_widget)

  [image: stopwatch widget]

Comment: It claims that I can't install iChrono widget as it is not a valid widget :-(

Comment: @Casebash, strange. I just installed iChrono without problems on my  mac. I run 10.6.4.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a dashboard widget, but the Apimac Timer application is free (there's a paid Pro version with additional features) and functions as a stopwatch, countdown timer, and alarm clock. Nice and handy.

http://www.apimac.com/timer/
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: couldn't you add this to the best apps?

Answer (score 4):

Menubar Countdown is good if you just want to countdown something
http://capablehands.net/menubarcountdown

License
Menubar Countdown is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

Comment: That is a very nice solution for when I want to keep track of how much time is left, but sometimes I want to set and forget

Answer (score 1):

For counting down a repeating task, Pomodoro is useful (and free):
http://pomodoro.ugolandini.com/

Answer (score 1):

**Not a widget**, but since there's always a browser around, the **[Timer Tab](http://www.timer-tab.com/) web app** does the trick for me.

[image: Timer-Tab.com]

Here's a selection of features:

- **timer** + **alarm clock** + **stopwatch**
- **works offline**
- **fullscreen** countdown by clicking on the countdown
- **keyboard control**:

  - <kbd>→</kbd>, <kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>↑</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd>: control inputs,
  - <kbd>f</kbd>: toggle fullscreen,
  - <kbd>space</kbd>: toggle pause
- **customizable**:

  - audio alarm: any Youtube clip
  - background: any image on the web
- countdown in the browser tab title and tab icon

---

Now, if Chrome happens to be the browser of your choice, there's also the [Chrome app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/edebbhkhcaafmolanelponjjanocpacd), providing you with some extra features:

- optional sound and Chrome notification
- use the "tab to search" chrome feature to set the timer
- etc.

---

Now, it's up to you to consider if this is a reasonable *alternative to a widget*.

Comment: but it's not a widget, as requested by the OP.

Comment: @DanielL agreed, and thanks for emphasizing it. I've edited my response to make it clearer that this is **not a widget**, but an *alternative*.

Comment: Unless of course, it can be made into a web clip and retain the necessary functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I know 2 of them:

1. [StopWatchWidget](http://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/status/stopwatchwidget.html)
2. [tTimer](http://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/sports/ttimer.html)

[image][image]

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @Casebash must asks whom voted.

Comment: Goodness, that first one is grotesque.